# Google cloud ml-engine custom hardware

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I tried running my job with `BASIC_GPU` scale tier but I got an out of memory error. So then I tried running it with a custom configuration but I can't find a way of just using 1 Nvidia K80 with additional memory. All examples and predefined options use a number of GPUs, CPUs and workers and my code is not optimized for that. I just want 1 GPU and additional memory. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

GPU memory is not extensible currently (Till something like [PASCAL](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/beyond-gpu-memory-limits-unified-memory-pascal/) is accessible)

Reducing the batch size solves some of the out of memory issues

Adding GPUs to workers doesn't help either, as the model is deployed on individual worker separately (No memory pooling b/n workers)